# Animate View from outside Layout to real position

Tags: android, animation, android-gridlayout

I have the next xml sctructure:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...>
    <RelativeLayout
        ...
        android:centerInParent=true/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/top_left"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/top_right"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
         </Linearlayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/middle_left"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/middle_right"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
         </Linearlayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/bottom_left"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/bottom_right"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
         </Linearlayout>

     </Linearlayout>

 </Relativelayout>
```

[image]

I need to place the views just like the picture (if the view have 4 squares, I need to place at the middle of those squares)

When the view has been loaded I need to anim all the views from the parent RelativeLayout center to the normal views position.

I tryed to do with a RelativeLayout as parent and animate all the views, but the views can change their size, so I don't know the final position of each view.

Is there anyway to implement with the structure written above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

simplest way to move any view:

```
view.animate().x(toX).y(toY).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is what you were asking but if I understand correctly, you want the Views to animate from the center of the screen to their correct positions in the layout. The idea to do this is to have each view start off with the property `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to ensure that they start off in the middle of the screen. Like so (I added colors so they are easier to see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:id="@+id/top_left"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/top_right"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>


<View
    android:id="@+id/middle_left"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/middle_right"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start animation"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in your code, you have to change the positions of the Views relative to each other.
Like so:

```
View tl = findViewById(R.id.top_left);
View tr = findViewById(R.id.top_right);
View ml = findViewById(R.id.middle_left);
View mr = findViewById(R.id.middle_right);

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) tl.getParent());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tl.getLayoutParams();
// Remove this property.
layoutParams1.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
// Position View in correct location.
layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
tl.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) tr.getParent());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tr.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams2.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
layoutParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.top_left);
tr.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) ml.getParent());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ml.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams3.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
layoutParams3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.top_left);
ml.setLayoutParams(layoutParams3);

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) mr.getParent());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams4 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mr.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams4.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
layoutParams4.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.top_right);
layoutParams4.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.middle_left);
mr.setLayoutParams(layoutParams4);
```

Comment: I edited the question with a picture, because the views must be just in the middle of the the first half, in the middle of the second half..

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, adding to all view's parents:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```